# AIR captive runtime for desktop, auto-install and open on double-click

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I'm packaging an AIR app with captive runtime.
I would like the potential users to have a possibility to install the app with just double-click even if they don't have AIR runtime installed (I thought that's what captive runtime is for). But in the output I get an .air-file which doesn't open automatically. So user is again asked to download/install runtime first.
So that's bad.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you're getting a .air file, you're not actually packaging the app with captive runtime.  Recheck your publish settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I had to pass `-target bundl`e in the compiler arguments before output.

In FlashDevelop:

```
 call adt -package %OPTIONS% %SIGNING_OPTIONS% -target bundle %OUTPUT% %APP_XML% %FILE_OR_DIR%
```